# Restoring a Postgresql 10 dump to Postgres 9.3 server

Tags: postgresql, compatibility

We are about to upgrade from pgsql 9.3 to 10.x. Part of the requirement is to be able to switch back to 9.3 in the case of some disaster (some massive but of course, unlikely incompatibility).

I tried pg_restoring a dump taken from one of our dev v. 10.x databases to a pgsql9.3 server, and got a lot of errors.

Is there any known "roll back path" from v 10.x to v 9.3?

Comment: backup and update use `pg_dump` the result will become `ddl` and `dml` statement and `psql` for restoring or update data..

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use `Pg_Dump` will give you a full `sql` file including all `DDL` and `DML` statements to recreate your database in another place (or restore).

You can do statement in `cmd` for backup use `Pg_Dump`

```
pg_dump -U username -d database > filename.sql
```

For more documentation and command use you can see here [*Pg_Dump*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

And you can restore use `Psql` command like this

```
psql -U username -d database -f filename.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pg_dump` from pg9.3 to backup the pg10 database. Then use that backup and `pg_restore` from pg9.3 again to restore.